# Replace specific string in HTML file with PHP

Tags: php, html, string, replace, find

I got this little problem here with my website. I want to replace a string in one of my html file. I did a php file that find the specific string and replace it but it become useless become the string to change is not the same after...

In my HTML file, I'm able to change `7NT0j5dB2QMyWv96nXIDgaR4PJ` for whatever random string the PHP file generate

```
<tr>
<td>Secret Key</td>
<td><strong style="color:#b94a48;">7NT0j5dB2QMyWv96nXIDgaR4PJ</strong></td>
</tr>
```

But in my PHP file the string to replace still `7NT0j5dB2QMyWv96nXIDgaR4PJ` not the new one...

There is my php code :

```
$contents = file_get_contents ("step-second-test.php");

$contents = str_replace(array("7NT0j5dB2QMyWv96nXIDgaR4PJ"), generateRandomString($length = 26), $contents);
file_put_contents("step-second-test.php", $contents);
```

Comment: Why not just directly echo the result of the function in step-second-test.php ?

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/R1K1d Maybe the problem is in `generateRandomString`, which you didn't include

Comment: ^ This means that what are you trying to replace __does not__ exist in a file. __OR__ this html part is created dynamically

Comment: @u_mulder OP's point is that `file_put_contents("step-second-test.php", $contents);` changes the file, meaning it is basically useless after the first run.

Comment: generateRandomString($length = 26) probably should be generateRandomString(26). Can you also post that function?

Comment: @PatrickQ Exactly! After the first run the script is useless because the php code look for the old string, not the new one he just changed...

Comment: I agree with @Patrick. Don't save the file, just echo the value.

Comment: Right, so see my original comment. Why not generate the random string in step-second-test.php?

Comment: function generateRandomString($length = 26) {
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
}

Comment: @PatrickQ how do I echo the function into the exact place the string need to go in my HTML file?

Comment: See here: https://3v4l.org/Uh6kV I see I'm late. Patrick already posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it's just a matter of moving the function call from wherever it is not to be directly in step-second-test.php

```
<tr>
<td>Secret Key</td>
<td><strong style="color:#b94a48;"><?php echo generateRandomString(26);
 ?></strong></td>
</tr>
```

Just make sure you also have the function definition in this file, or have an `include()` to the file that has the function definition.

Comment: @jamesbub don't forget to upvote and/or accept if you like the answer. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you use `step-second-test.php` as static file which changes over time. To handle your problem you either convert you `step-second-test.php` to dynamic file like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Secret Key</td>
<td><strong style="color:#b94a48;"><?php echo generateRandomString(26); ?></strong></td>
</tr>
```

And from now on you `include 'step-second-test.php';` in your php scripts instead of using `file_get_contents`. Remember, though, that `generateRandomString` needs to be accessible.

If you want to stick to what you have you need to change your thinking. Problem is not replacing "7NT0j5dB2QMyWv96nXIDgaR4PJ" with whatever else but replacing whatever is between `<strong>` tags with whatever else.

With problem stated as such there are many options the easiest of which I find using [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). PHP makes the problem easier by providing [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). So solution to your problem would be:

```
$contents = file_get_contents ("step-second-test.php");

$pattern = '/(.*<strong.*>).*(<\/strong>.*)/i';
$replacement = '${1}' . generateRandomString($length = 26) . '${2}';
$contents = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents);

file_put_contents("step-second-test.php", $contents);
```

If you don't know regular expressions I recommend [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) for learning and playing around with them. Regular expressions are great thing. Mandatory for any programmer. Nice to know for any computer user.

Comment: Thanks Alek! Good answer too ! :)

Comment: FYI, this will replace _all_ instances of text within `<strong></strong>` tags. For the limited example given above, that may be fine, but on a larger scale, using regex to parse HTML is rarely the way to go.

Comment: I use the solution of @PatrickQ and it's working perfectly fine! Thanks again guys!